# ActiveRecord query syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
@past_topics = Topic.includes(:user, :event).where("event_id IS NOT NULL "cached_votes_up DESC").page(params[:page]).per(6)
```

That's my code.

How to add `event.date < DateTime.now` to this code on `where` condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just append it :)

```
@past_topics = ... # your code
@past_topics = @past_topics.where('events.date < ?', DateTime.now)
```

Comment: Exactly. ActiveRecord creates a query object which gets evaluated when you call an enumerator method or when you call methods like `all` or `first`. If you leave out those calls, the query won't be executed. So you cann append further method calls (`order`, `where`, etc, pp) until you called `first`, `last`, `all` or an enumerator.